# Conflict with multiple insert in two tables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, bulkinsert

I am trying to insert all the rows of `cart` Table of `userId=1` into `Order` and `OrderItem` table the Order table consists of following columns:

### **ORDER TABLE**

1.OrderId (int)

2.OrderDate(datetime)

3.userId (int)

4.orderStatus (varchar)

the `user_tbl`table is reference to the `Order` table with PK of userId and
 `cart` table is also reference with userId

**CART TABLE**

Id

userId

Quantity

productID

**ORDERITEM TABLE**

id

orderid

productid

qty

**ITEM Table**

ProductId

Name

SizeId

ColorId

Price

Imageurl

I have tried following but this giving me conflict error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_OrderItem_Item". The conflict occurred in database "db", table "dbo.Item", column 'Id'

```
insert into [Order] values(getdate(),@userId,@status);
set @orderId = @@IDENTITY
insert into OrderItem (OrderId ,ItemID,Qty,ColorId,SizeId)
select @orderId,Cart.ProductId,cart.Quantity,cart.ColorId,cart.SizeId 
from [Cart] 
where UserId=@userId ;
```

Comment: I have no idea why this received an upvote. Without some details this is guess work. Which of your two inserts causes the error? Probably the second one? Can you share the ddl of your table AND the foreign key? My guess is you are trying to put something in OrderItem that doesn't exist in your Item table (but that table isn't in your question).

Comment: I checked the item table the record is not exists that is causing the error ----Thanks

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Next time please post actual ddl (create table statements) instead of a list of columns. It would make your questions a lot easier to help with.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Query as Below

```
INSERT INTO [Order]
VALUES
(
    GETDATE(),
    @userId,
    @status
);

SELECT @orderId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();--Use SCOPE_IDENTITY Instead of @@IDENTITY

INSERT INTO OrderItem
(
    OrderId,
    ItemID,
    Qty,
    ColorId,
    SizeId
)
       SELECT [Order].OrderId,
              Cart.ProductId,
              cart.Quantity,
              cart.ColorId,
              cart.SizeId
       FROM [Cart] 
       INNER JOIN [Order]
       ON [Cart].UserId = @userId
          AND [Order].OrderId = @orderId;--SELECT Order Id From Order to be more safer
```

Comment: same result it is conflicting with Item table with column ID

Comment: Why a cross join and then be forced to use a where predicate to turn it back into an inner join? Why not simply use inner join? I totally agree about SCOPE_IDENTITY but the issue is something is violating a foreign key....and we have no idea what the foreign key is.

Comment: The issue was with the item table in which the ProductId reference to orderitem table there is missing productid (row) in item table .

Comment: As OP has figured out, there are at least 2 FKs in a detail table. One to the order and one to the "thing" that was ordered. Exactly how one can add an item to a cart without it existing in the item table is a concerning but different problem.